# Trying to connect in VBA, ADO to localhost MySQL

Tags: mysql, vba

I'm using

```
Sub fff()
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
ConnectionString = "{MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};Server=localhost;Database=test;User=root;"

cn.Open ConnectionString
cn.Close
Set cn = Nothing
MsgBox "connected"
```

I'm running Office 32b on Win 64b
I've installed MySql drivers as shown here:

[image]

I get the error

[image]

Comment: `c:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe.` Check if ODBC datasource is defined in 32-bit mode. If not then define it and check your code again.

Comment: They are defined as "32/64 bits" in user dsn tab. Still get the error. The connection is "successful" when defining the datasources and testing it. Is there some other way to Check if ODBC datasource is defined in 32-bit mode?